# Topology on $C_{compact}^{\infty}(R)$

Tags: general-topology, distribution-theory

Want to show that the topology on  $C_{\mathrm{compact}}^{\infty}(R)$, which is given by all the good semi-norms, is generated by the following collection of semi-norms $\| \cdot\|_{m,\epsilon}$

$m=\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing positive integer sequence,

$\epsilon=\{\epsilon_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence converging to zero from above.

$K_{i}=[-i,+i],\quad K_{0}=\phi$ ,

$\|\psi\|_{m,\epsilon}=\sup_{n\ge0}\epsilon_{n}^{-1}\sup_{x\notin K_{n}}\sum_{m_{n}\ge j\ge0}|D^{j}\psi(x)|$

I proved that $||\cdot||_{m,\epsilon}$ is a good semi-norm. How to show that every good semi-norm can be cast in to this form? Is this statement even true? Thanks.

good seminorm means  it is continous in $C_{\mathrm{compact}}^{\infty}(K)$ for all compact $K$

Topology in $C_{\mathrm{compact}}^{\infty}(K)$ is induced by $\{\| \cdot\|_{C^{0}},...,\| \cdot\|_{C^{n}},...\}$
$\|\psi\|_{C^{k}}=\sup_{x\in K}\sum_{k\ge j\ge0}|D^{j}\psi(x)|$

Comment: What is a "good semi-norm"?

Comment: Continuous in every space of smooth function compactly supported in a compact subset of R

Comment: Equipped with what topology?

Comment: Are you equipping the $C^\infty(K)$, $K$ compact, with the topology defined by the family of semi-norms $$\|f\|_m=\sup_{x\in K}|f^{(m)}(x)|\;?$$

Comment: yeah just edited my post